# Validation and Invalidation in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am new in flex and recently read about **Validation and Invalidation in components**. May somebody explain what it's mean and when it's use, may be some good article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the chapter ["About creating advanced components"](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Part4_CreateComps_1.html) from the Adobe Flex LiveDocs will be a good starting point. Take notice of the subchapter "About the invalidation methods".

Answer (score 2):

some links for you to learn
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/validators_2.html

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/13/validating-flex-forms-using-the-validator-classes/